# Curve corners of rectangle in c# without loosing the lineargradient colors of the button

Tags: c#, .net

I have this class that would create a rectangle button.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {

        base.OnPaint(pevent);
        Color c1 = Color.FromArgb(m_color1transparent, m_color1);
        Color c2 = Color.FromArgb(m_color2transparent, m_color2);
        Brush b = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(ClientRectangle, c1, c2, 10);
        pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, ClientRectangle);
        b.Dispose();    

    }
```

My question is how can I add or make a curve on each corners of the rectangle?

Comment: Here is a more neater example http://tech.pro/tutorial/656/csharp-creating-rounded-rectangles-using-a-graphics-path

Comment: I have already tried that but when i add the code it will not  create the lineargradient color anymore. what I am trying to achieve is how to make it curve without removing the lineargradient .

Comment: @PeterDuniho could you please help me to draw a rounded rectangle with a lineargradient?I want a  button with a rounded rectangle with linear colors.

Comment: Have a look at a GraphicsPath to set a Cliping Region on the Button!

Answer (score 3):

This is a simplified example for a regular `Button` on a `Form`. It does **not** create a rounded rectangle but an `Ellipse`. It demonstrates the use of a `GraphicsPath` and `Graphics.Clip` with a `Region`.

To create a  rounded rectangle simply change the `GraphicsPath` as in the code examples for the links in the comments!

```
private void button5_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.Clear(button5.BackColor);  // omit or change  appropriately!
    Color c1 = Color.Red;
    Color c2 = Color.BlueViolet;
    using (Brush b = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(
                         e.ClipRectangle, c1, c2, 10))
    {
        GraphicsPath GP = new GraphicsPath();
        GP.AddEllipse(e.ClipRectangle);
        e.Graphics.Clip = new System.Drawing.Region(GP);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, e.ClipRectangle);
    }
}
```

I have used plain colors and have changed your use of `ClientRectangle` to `e.ClipRectangle`, which may be unnecessary if you create a subclass of Button..

**Update:**  There are several ways to do it, using `Lines` and `Arcs` for exmaple.. Without checking the above links here is one other way to do it; given a corner radius `CR` simply replace the `GP.AddEllipse(e.ClipRectangle);`  with this:

```
    int w = e.ClipRectangle.Width;
    int h = e.ClipRectangle.Height;
    int CR2 = CR + CR ;
    Region Reg = new Region(Rectangle.Empty);
    Reg.Union(new Rectangle(CR, 0, w - CR2, h));
    Reg.Union(new Rectangle(0, CR, w, h - CR2));

    GraphicsPath GP = new GraphicsPath();
    GP.AddEllipse(new Rectangle(0, 0, CR2, CR2));
    GP.AddEllipse(new Rectangle(w - CR2, 0, CR2, CR2));
    GP.AddEllipse(new Rectangle(w - CR2 , h - CR2 , CR2, CR2));
    GP.AddEllipse(new Rectangle(0, h - CR2 , CR2, CR2));
    Reg.Union(GP);
```

Comment: Hi Taw I am now more closer to achieve it but my problem is I think the Clip. Whenever i tried to resize the button the clip will not resize.

Comment: Note that I had left out the correct `e.ClipRectangle` for the `FillRectangle` call (of all places..)! - Do you subclass Button or are you in a regular form?

Comment: Also please see the greatly simplified way to do it, now! This should work after resizing without problems; it vertainly does here, (unless I shrink it to be smaller than the corner radius..)

Comment: This is my new code for it.

Comment: Um, was that a question, or a link?

Comment: base.OnPaint(pevent);
GraphicsPath path = RoundedRectangle.Create(30, 5, 115, 50);
Color c1 = Color.FromArgb(m_color1transparent, m_color1);
Color c2 = Color.FromArgb(m_color2transparent, m_color2);
Brush b =  new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(pevent.ClipRectangle, c1, c2, 10);
pevent.Graphics.Clip = new System.Drawing.Region(path);
pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, ClientRectangle);
b.Dispose();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64998/discussion-between-taw-and-androidz).

Comment: Taw im on there already in the chat room